# Tabela dinâmica utilizando Reactive Forms

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Usando ReactiveForm montei uma tabela para o usuário poder adicionar as matérias primas de um determinado produto. O usuário seleciona em um `mat-select` e adiciono uma nova linha na tabela (`mat-table`).

As colunas da tabela são: Item, Quantidade, Valor, Subtotal. 
A adição de novas linhas funciona muito bem, porém não estou conseguindo calcular o subtotal da linha. Na verdade já consegui, mas só atualizando todas as linhas da tabela, o faz com que o campo perca o foco, e fiz isso da seguinte form:

```
this.materiasPrimaForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  this.rowsMateriasPrima = this.materiasPrimaForm.value;
});
```

O `formgroup` utilizado é esse:

```
    this.setFormGroup({
      nome: ["", [Validators.required]],
      descricao: ["", [Validators.required]],
      foto: [""],
      materiasPrima: this.fb.array([]),
      processos: this.fb.array([]),
      cores: ['', Validators.required],
    });
```

Essas são minhas colunas

```
// O datasource da tabela é a variável rowsMateriasPrima
<ng-container matColumnDef="quantidade">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-fit-cell"> Quantidade </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let materiaprima;let rowIndex=index;" [formGroupName]="rowIndex" class="mat-fit-cell" >
    <input type="text" formControlName="quantidade" #materiaPrimaQuantidade/> 
  </td>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="valor">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-fit-cell"> Valor </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let materiaprima;let rowIndex=index;"[formGroupName]="rowIndex"  class="mat-fit-cell"> 
    <input type="text" formControlName="valor" #materiaPrimaValor/> 
  </td>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="subtotal">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-fit-cell"> Subtotal </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let materiaprima" class="mat-fit-cell"> 
    {{materiaPrimaQuantidade.value * materiaPrimaValor.value | currency:'BRL':true}} 
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Quando executo recebo o erro `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`, na coluna subtotal.

**Como calcular o subtotal da linha conforme o usuário informar os valores?**

---

EDIT:
Consegui fazer, mas não sei se é a melhor forma:

No template da coluna subtotal

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let materiaprima;let rowIndex=index;" class="mat-fit-cell"> {{getSubTotalMateriaPrima(rowIndex) | currency:'BRL':true}} </td>
```

```
  getSubTotalMateriaPrima(rowIndex) {
    const { valor, quantidade } = this.materiasPrimaForm.value[rowIndex];
    return valor * quantidade;
  }
```

O que acham?

---

EDIT2:

subscribe para alterações no formulário:

```
    this.materiasPrimaForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      this.updateMateriaPrimaSubTotal();
      this.updateCustoProducao();
    });
/* ... */
  updateMateriaPrimaSubTotal() {
    for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < this.materiasPrimaForm.value.length; rowIndex++) {
      const { valor, quantidade } = this.materiasPrimaForm.value[rowIndex];
      this.subTotalMateriaPrima[rowIndex] = valor * quantidade;
    }
  }
```

No layout:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let materiaprima;let rowIndex=index;"> {{subTotalMateriaPrima[rowIndex] | currency:'BRL'}} </td>
```

Comment: é melhor vc criar uma popriedade e setar ela onChange do form. Desse jeito ele vai chamar sua função muitas vezes.

Comment: Fiz isso para calcular a soma das materias prima. Como posso fazer isso para a linha? `subtotalMateriaPrima[__id__] = valor` ?

Comment: @EduardoVargas dessa forma também funcionou. E realmente, da forma que que havia feito a função era chamada 8 vezes, enquanto a com a propriedade era chamada apenas uma vez.